# How can I make TextField's suffix/suffixIcon height resize?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffix: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('222');
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I force the *check_circle* icon to automatically resize to match the height of the actual TextField, i.e., wrt its cursor height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good question...

The basics, is to reset all the paddings in the TextField, and not using a IconButton (as all Material components have predefined and internals paddings that you can't modify).

Seems like suffix gets baseline aligned with the text, preventing the material ink interaction, while suffixIcons get properly centered in the text area, BUT propagates the Ink to the TextField.
So, so far I couldn't find a way of doing it properly, maybe there's a widget/logic that I'm missing.

Check screenshot at the bottom that shows why the suffix will not be able to align with the text, as it sits within the baseline itself, and the caret generates a bigger height.....

in the first 2 textfields, the GREY boxes are suffix, and yellow, suffixIcon (which centers properly).

**Solution 1:** (in screenshotm is red background with 2 checkboxes)
If you can (design-wise), make a row, and put the TextField and the icon:

```
var inputBorderDecoration = OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black));

    double textHeight = 40;

    // define a width if you want, or let the constrains of the parent define it.
    double inputWidth = double.infinity;

    return Center(
      child: Container(
          width: inputWidth,
          height: textHeight,
          color: Colors.green.withOpacity(.2),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(text: 'hello world'),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: textHeight),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    enabledBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    focusedBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(.5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FittedBox(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print("touch button"),
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
```

**Solution 2:** (in screenshot, last textfield, green box with white icon)
Wrap the icon decoration, is the better UI approach, but the TextField will .still receive touch events.

```
var inputBorderDecoration = OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black));

    double fontSize = 24;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green.shade50,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: fontSize,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(.5),
                    filled: true,
                    border: inputBorderDecoration,
                    focusedBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    enabledBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => print('on tap'),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                          child: IconTheme(
                            data: IconThemeData(),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.check_circle,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Solution 3:**

Build the decorations yourself using [EditableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText-class.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer but when I cranked the textScaleFactor upto 2.0, the text came out of the container.

Answer (score 6):

Use `suffixIcon` instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('222');
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That did not work; icon remained the same size, irrespective of the font size scale specified in phones accessibility settings.

Answer (score 4):

Used `Stack`

```
Stack(
                    children: [
                      TextField(),
                      Positioned.fill(
                          right: 10,
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    searchController.clear();
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.clear))))
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of decoration. You can modify the `suffixIconConstraints`, to a size of your choice. Like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      onChanged: widget.onTextChanged,
      onEditingComplete: () {
        if (widget.enableAvailabilityCheck &&
            widget.availabilityCheck != null) {
          performAvailabilityCheck();
        }
      },
      obscureText: widget.obscureText && !isObscureTextVisible,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: widget.enableAvailabilityCheck
              ? buildSuffixIcon()
              : widget.obscureText
                  ? buildObscureTextIcon()
                  : null,
          suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(24.0, 24.0))),
    );
  }
```